# How to change particular word color in React Native Text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Please check the image-
how can I do that in my react native app
[image]

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet, Switch} from 'react-native';

const Testing = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
   <View>
     <Text> My mother has blue eyes and my father has dark green eyes.</Text>
</View>
  );

}

export default Testing;
```

Comment: Take a look at Reactnative docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text.

Answer (score 4):

Text elements have to be nested:

```
const Testing = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
   <View>
     <Text> My mother has <Text style={{color: '#0000fff'}}>blue<Text> eyes and my father has dark green eyes.</Text>
</View>
  );

}
```

Example: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#nested-text

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<Text>` inside another `<Text>` and add a style for each text. Like the code bellow:

```
<Text style={styles.text}> text text text text text 
    <Text onPress={() => goToScreen('Premiações')} style={styles.blue_text}> 
        differently styled text 
    </Text> 
text text.
</Text>
```

Perceive my inner `<Text>` has a style different from the outter `<Text>`, and also perceive my inner `<Text>` has even a `onPress`, which will be applied only to this inner `<Text>` when pressed (it's a link inside the body of a text).